# How to read and parse incoming message from kafka broker in a consumer?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro

I am new to Kafka.I am trying to write a consumer. I am getting data from multiple tables of a database using only a single kafka topic. The messages which are coming in the below format:

{"TABLE":{"string": "TABLE1"},"NAME":{"string":"JOHN"},"AGE":{"string":"26"},"ADDRESS":{"string":"USA"}

{"TABLE":{"string": "TABLE2"},"NAME":{"string":"RYAN"},"AGE":{"string":"30"},"ADDRESS":{"string":"CANADA"},"PIN":{"string":"000001"},"PHN":null,"STATUS":{"string":"MARRIED"}}

What kind of data format it is? JSON or AVRO?
How to parse this using scala?

Comment: CDC from Debezium? Are you using Schema Registry? Seen related questions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark%2bconfluent-schema-registry?tab=Votes

Comment: My source database is Oracle. informatica publisher is publishing messages to the Kafka broker. I am not using confluent kafka.

Comment: Okay, then have you seen Spark documentation on their Avro support? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro

Answer (score 0):

its json. you may parse it as:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON


val result = JSON.parseFull("""{"TABLE":{"string": "TABLE1"},"NAME":{"string":"JOHN"},"AGE":{"string":"26"},"ADDRESS":{"string":"USA"}""")
```